# Friend name resolving scope in C++

Tags: c++, g++

This is legacy code that likely worked in era 3.2 or 2.8 g++, but no longer. It does still compile under microsoft C/C++ optimizing compiler v.17. The code has also been trimmed down from the original to isolate the salient issue.

*in function +=, error: 'to_every' was not declared in this scope*

```
class Matrix {};

class ElementWiseConst
{
public:
  ElementWiseConst(const Matrix& m){}
};

class ElementWise : public ElementWiseConst
{
public:
  ElementWise(const ElementWise&);
  ElementWise(Matrix& m) : ElementWiseConst(m) {}
  void operator +=  (const double val); 
  friend ElementWise to_every(Matrix& m) { return m; }
};

Matrix& operator += (Matrix& m, const double val) { 
  to_every(m) += val; 
  return m; 
}
```

Is this an implicit conversion or scoping that microsoft is incorrectly allowing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_every` is defined inside of `ElementWise` and thus can only be found via [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). The compiler will look at the arguments provided and use its associated namespaces and classes to find the name `to_every`. The associate classes of `Matrix` is `Matrix` itself and its associated namespace is the global namespace (assuming it was declared there). `ElementWise` needs to be an associated class, thus `to_every` cannot be found.

To get this to work you can:

- Define `to_every` outside of the class.
- Make `ElementWise` an associated class by making it a template argument (@sehe):

  ```
  template<class T>
  class ADLMatrix {};

  using Matrix = ADLMatrix<class ElementWise>;
  ```

Comment: Either of the above solutions works, but ended up defining to_every as a global utility function as it was more convenient and this was only legacy code after all.